# React Fragment isn't working for Input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there any other way I can write the following code without resorting to React.Fragment because that's not working.

```
          <FormGroup>
            <Input type="select" name="selectMultiPrefs" id="MultiPrefs" multiple>
              {this.state.arrayForCategs.map(function (CategName, index) {
                return (
                   <React.Fragment key={keyNum++}>
                    <option key={keyNum++} value={CategName} disabled>{CategName}</option>
                 {that.props.general.adprefrec.map(function (AdSingle, index) {
                   <option key={keyNum++} value={AdSingle.prefid}>{AdSingle.name}</option>
                 })}
                   </React.Fragment>
                )
              })}
            </Input>
          </FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because there is no such thing as `<Input type="select">`.

You want to use `<select>`.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag